# Alternative solutions for running selenium tests concurrently on multiple mobile devices with Appium

Tags: selenium, mobile, junit, concurrency, appium

I have a test setup for mobile devices which I am able to run concurrently on mobile devices. However I feel like my solution could be improved and made more elegant and I am hoping for some advice on how to do this.

The solution I have now looks like the following:

I have a unit test with Junit and this test contains a properties file.
In this properties file I set a portnr which the script should use to connect to a appium instance.

Then for each device I have a .bat file that does the following:

- Set the portnr to the properties file.
- Start appium instance with that portnr.
- Compile script with maven and start unittest.

Now this solution works, although I had to give each appium instance its own app package to prevent concurrency issues. Also I have to start these .bat files not at the same moment because that might cause issues writing to the properties file.

So I'm looking at different angles on  how to solve this problem, for example creating a new thread at the toplevel of the unittest for each device. However I don't know how to do this. I only have @BeforeClass and @BeforeTest hooks, and I don't know how to arrange things on the unittest level instead of class level.

Please share your experiences!